# Objective-C JSON Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am a new iOS Developer, who has a big app to write.
First we have a server where is the jason. I have to get data from that server and parse it. And display the data in various places on display like UIView.
But, the problem is, I can connect to server, get data, and parse it, but i cannot display data in brackets.
Let me explain:

Our JSON Data is this:

```
{
"mbsServer": {
    "version": 1,
    "serverTime": 1374400122,
    "status": 2000,
    "subscriptionExpireTime": 1575057600,
    "channel": {
        "id" : 47,
        "name" : "Yurd TV",
        "logo" : "XXX.png",
        "screenshot" : "screen.png",
        "packageId" : 0,
        "viewers": 1,
        "access": true,
        "streams" : [
                {
                    "birate" : 200,
                    "hls"  : "xxxx.m2u8",
                    "rtsp" : "RTSP.xx"
                },
                {
                    "birate" : 500,
                    "hls"  : "xxxxx",
                    "rtsp" : "xxxxx"
                }
        ]
    }

}
}
```

I want to get `objectForKey:@"hls"`, but I cannot. It is just gicing me the all the data from JSON. My code looks like this:

```
NSData *JSONData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentOfURL: [NSURL URLLWithString:@"XXXXXXXXXXX"]];
NSArray *streams = [JSONData objectFromJSONData];
for(NSDictionary *hls in streams)
{
   NSLog(@"%@", [hls objectForKey:@"hls"]);
}
```

Please help...

Comment: Before you do anything else, go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn, and understanding it is critical to being able to solve this type of problem (so that you won't have to come back here and ask again for every new/changed JSON layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't get `streams` array properly. Try the following:

```
NSObject *json = [JSONData objectFromJSONData];
NSArray *streams = [json valueForKeyPath:@"mbsServer.channel.streams"];
for (NSDictionary *stream in streams)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [stream valueForKey:@"hls"]);
}
```

Comment: Alex Skalozub, you saved my life :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The root object should be an `NSDictionary` instead of `NSArray` - or if you want to get the streams array from the JSON, then you are accessing it wrong - see the answer of [Alex Skalozub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17771153/1001803).